# SQLite - no such table: while using CTE for deleting duplicate records

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have created a Contacts table (Name, Phone, Email) and i have some duplicated records that i want to delete

```
WITH ContactsCTE AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) as RowNumber
    FROM Contacts
)
SELECT * FROM ContactsCTE
```

When i use SELECT it shows the data and rowNumber of them and i guess it works fine

```
| Name | Phone |     Email      | RowNumber |
| Kris | 0123  | kris@gmail.com |     1     |
| Kris | 0123  | kris@gmail.com |     2     |
| Kris | 0123  | kris@gmail.com |     3     |
| Annie| 065   | annie@gmail.com|     1     |
| Bob  | 0123  | bob@gmail.com  |     1     |
| Bob  | 0123  | bob@gmail.com  |     2     |
```

But if i want to DELETE them

```
 WITH ContactsCTE AS (
        SELECT *, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) as RowNumber
        FROM Contacts
    )
 DELETE FROM ContactsCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

I get this message : 
**"Result: no such table: ContactsCTE"**
At line 1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support updateable CTEs.
You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM Contacts 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Contacts c  
  WHERE c.Name = Contacts.Name AND c.rowid < Contacts.rowid
);
```

This will delete all rows for which there exists another row with the same name and smaller [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ve5AwdgPcNnjKRGirNeBoy/1).

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Contacts 
WHERE rowid > (
  SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM Contacts c  
  WHERE c.Name = Contacts.Name
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ve5AwdgPcNnjKRGirNeBoy/2).
Results:

```
| Name  | Phone | Email           |
| ----- | ----- | --------------- |
| Kris  | 123   | kris@gmail.com  |
| Annie | 65    | annie@gmail.com |
| Bob   | 123   | bob@gmail.com   |
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

One workaround as follows.

Instead of using "DELETE FROM ContactsCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1,"
use SELECT * FROM ContactsCTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1;

Comment: How will this delete the rows from the table?

Comment: It selects RowNumber = 1, which is equivalent to dropping all rows with RowNumber > 1.

Comment: How is selecting equivalent to deleting?

Comment: didn't you get the same result?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between [SELECT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select/) and [DELETE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-delete/)?

Comment: I know the differences. But do I need to know that in this case? Didn't what I did accomplish the mission? I said from the first place it's a workaround. Did you vote for my post?

Comment: From the question: *...i have some duplicated records that i want to delete...* So, no, **your answer does not accomplish the mission** because it does not delete anything. I downvoted your post because after all the comments I left you did nothing to correct it. Why did you downvote my answer which was accepted by the OP because it is a solution for their problem?

Comment: You seems to be a dinosaur. How can you say my answer does not accomplish the mission when the results are all the same and created a new table? Do you really need to hang on the difference of 'select' and 'delete'? The original poster was using WITH cte and want to create a new table, which your code did not.  His table Contracts doesn't have duplicates. The duplicates are in the ContactsCTE. This makes sense to you? You don't know what the OP think of my answer. I voted down yours because I don't think you "accomplish the mission."

Comment: It seems that you are totally ignorant of the basics of SQL. The OP thought that by using a CTE they could delete its results. This is the reason that they are using DELETE. But, SQLite does not allow deletions of the results of the CTE. This is the reason my answer does not use a CTE. Is there a case that you understand anything from what I mentioned? I don't think so. If you did you wouldn't say: "His table Contracts doesn't have duplicates" when you can read in the question: "I have created a Contacts table (Name, Phone, Email) and i have some duplicated records that i want to delete"

Comment: I admit I misread that part. But the table ContractsCTE from my answer has exactly what the OP needs and the results are the same as yours. Does this not deserve a 'mission accomplished?' I am not a sql expert and am not pretending to be one. But your action of downvoting my post is unacceptable, although I don't care about how many points I have.

Comment: You did not misread only that part. You misread the whole question and what's worse is that you still do not understand. Your code does not delete anything. After it is finished the OP's table will be just as it was before with all 6 rows: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ve5AwdgPcNnjKRGirNeBoy/5 This is not what the question asks for.

Comment: I did not say the duplicates in Contracts were deleted. The table ContractsCTE is what is needed, which can be used to replace the Contracts or whatsoever.

Comment: ContractsCTE is not a table. It is a CTE (Common Table Expression: https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-common-table-expression/) and it is not what is needed. Take some time to read about SQL and come back to answer questions. I'm done here.